# Memory cost using UIViewControllers.view or UIView directly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Hi everyone, sorry my English is not good.

I have the next question: what is better to add a view (My question is about the cost of memory and better programing methods)

Like this:

```
UIViewController *vcToAdd = [[UIViewController alloc]
                             initWithNibName:@"vcxib"
                             bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.view addSubview:vcToAdd.view];
```

Or like this:

```
NSArray *xibsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                      loadNibNamed:@"MMList_iPhone" owner:nil options:nil];

UIView *vwToAdd = [xibsArray objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:vwToAdd];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you own the UIViewController you create, this means you are responsible for releasing it. If you don't release it, there will probably be a leak somewhere.

```
UIViewController *vcToAdd = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"vcxib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.view addSubview:vcToAdd.view];
[vcToAdd release];
```

In the second case you DON'T own the content of the Nib file. So you aren't responsible for managing memory. Anyway, here you are getting the content of a Nib file and presenting it "as it is". Without a UIViewController that controls its behavior.

If the view contained in your Nib file needs some complex management, for example animations or getting touches, UIViewController way is probably what you're looking for...

Take a look at Apple's Memory Management Guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) (in English).

EDIT: There is a third way... Create your view programmatically without using Nib files.

```
// Create your content view
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
// Add objects to it
UIButton *button = [UIButton ...
UILabel *label = [UILabel ...
[view addSubview:button];
[view addSubview:label];
...
// Put your content view on screen
[self.view addSubview:view];
// Free memory
[view release];
```

Comment: Thanks Beppe what do you prefer to use ??

Comment: You are welcome!!! :D I prefer first way, otherwise I create everything in code, without Nib file (take a look at my EDIT).

Comment: Beppe can you help me with this thanks.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150406/viewconroller-view-removefromsuperview-thread1-exc-bad-access-code-1-addres)

Comment: "If the view contained in your Nib file needs some complex management, for example animations or getting touches, UIViewController way is probably what you're looking for..."
This is not correct, one can do getting touches and animations perfectly by using UIView alone. And you can load custom UIView classes with IBOutlet bindings from a NIB file.
What a controller does is managing interaction between the views in one screen. And providing model for the views.