# (viewConroller.view removeFromSuperview) Thread:1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address = 0x6000000008)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

(^.^) Hi sorry for my English is not good.

Hi I have the next issue I create 2 buttons the first one button create one view controller and add his view to other viewcontroller the second button I release the view controller created and remove the view from the parent.
If I tap faster the 2 buttons crash with the message like in the post Title this is the code

(I now this is because memory problems but what is the problem?? I do this only for see the memory managment with XCODE-PROFIL-INSTRUMENTS-Allocations please Help):

```
- (IBAction)create:(id)sender{
       vc = nil;
       vc = [[[VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] retain];
      [_VW addSubview:vc.view];
}
```

And kill with this button:

```
- (IBAction)kill:(id)sender{
      [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
      [vc release];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you press the button fast, at least in the kill button's case, it attempts to `release` the view however many times you press the button (assuming the code works when you press the button only once). The EXC_BAD_ACCESS code means you are trying to access some memory location that has already been released.

The best way to protect against this would be to use the `[NSButton setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled]` method. When the create button is pressed, enable the kill button and disable the create button. When the kill button is pressed, disable the kill button and enable the create button. This will prevent accidental extra allocations or releases.

Also, in your create method, you should remove that extra `retain` in `vc`'s allocation line. `alloc` automatically increments the retain count (to 1), and that extra retain is bringing it up to 2. With the way it is, when the kill button is pressed, the object is released once, but the retain count is still 1, creating a memory leak.

Comment: Hi I'm again wquist can you help me with this pelase [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151224/memory-dont-decreases-when-releasing-objects) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `vc` is an iVar, so you should not send `release` in `kill:` method. So just remove the code line:

```
[vc release];
```

and add it to your `dealloc` method.

---

Note, it's better to use the code like below for your `create:`

```
if (vc == nil)
  vc = [[[VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] retain];
[_VW addSubview:vc.view];
```

Otherwise, when your `vc` is not nil, it'll lead a memory leak.

Comment: Hi I'm again Kjuly can you help me with this please [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151224/memory-dont-decreases-when-releasing-objects) Thanks