# Memory dont decreases When releasing objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

(^.^)"Hi again sorry for my English is not good if someone like correct my redaction I would appreciate this"

Yes you're right. but:
First when I click the create button this create new View Controller with alloc, and retain count  +1 automatically and when I press kill button the retain count -1 and Equals 0 this means the View Controller created **in theory it was removed form the memory** I corrected the code so:

```
- (IBAction)create:(id)sender{
    if(vc == nil){ //if is not nil this mean vc have some space of memory reference and vc is not created
    //if == nil this mean vc does not have space of memory reference so create.
    vc = [[VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];// retain count + 1
    [_VW addSubview:vc.view];
}
```

and

```
  - (IBAction)kill:(id)sender{
    [vc.view removeFromSuperview]; //When view removeFromSuperview is called also dealloc is called of the vc view
    [vc release];// retain count - 1  the curren count is equal 0 this mean vc does not have space of memory
     vc = nil; // remove the reference of memory.
  }
```

**But when I make the profile of the proyect and I click the button create and kill the memory don't decrease only grows **

Sorry But I cant paste the image because i'm Newbie posting but when I init the profile in Allocations init with Live Bytes 584,19kb  and in 1 minute Live Bytes are in 1,08 mb dont release nothing only grow.

I don´t now why if I create and free correctly please Help.

Comment: Well, @RIP's answer is what I suggest [BEFORE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150406/viewconroller-view-removefromsuperview-thread1-exc-bad-access-code-1-addres/10150623#comment13018709_10150623), but with a detail code sample. :)

Comment: And btw, I think you should put `[_VW addSubview:vc.view];` out of `if {}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following two way - 
1. Allocating once and release in dealloc -

```
- (IBAction)create:(id)sender{
    if(vc == nil){ 
        vc = [[VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [_VW addSubview:vc.view];
    }
}

- (IBAction)kill:(id)sender{
    [vc.view removeFromSuperview]; 
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [vc release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

2. Allocating every time and releasing as well-

```
- (IBAction)create:(id)sender{
    if(vc == nil){ 
        vc = [[[VC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorealease];
        [_VW addSubview:vc.view];
    }
}

- (IBAction)kill:(id)sender{
    [vc.view removeFromSuperview]; 
}
```

Now you can try with any of these and then check the memory footprint.

Comment: have you checked with object graph for free and used memory?

Comment: (^.^)"Hi again sorry for my English is not good if someone like correct my redaction I would appreciate this"

Thanks RIP I will prove this tomorrow rather in a couple of hours hahahaha  I'm soy tired mmm I use the profile with Allocations and see the alive bytes. but what you think my code should work? why don't work in theory it has to work right? I appreciate your help, Thanks.